# Connect from Android unity c# client to python server

Tags: python, c#, android

I have a basic `python server` listening for a connection on my `IP address`. I also have a basic `c# client` that runs on `unity`. When I run it from my `pc` the connection is established but when I build the apk and run it on my `android` phone nothing happens. I have never done anything related to a connection between two devices so I am pretty noob. What is stopping the client on my phone from connecting to the server and how can  I fix it?

I censored my IP for demo purposes.
Server Code:

```py
import socket
import threading
HOST = '123.123.123.1'  # Change to your ip
PORT = 123


class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server_socket = None
        self.client1 = None
        self.client2 = None
        self.client1_thread = None
        self.client2_thread = None

    def __del__(self):
        if self.server_socket is not None:
            self.server_socket.close()
        print("Server shutdown successful")

    def setup_server_and_bind(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
        self.server_socket.listen(10)
        print("Listening")

    def connect_to_clients(self):
        print("Waiting for users to request connection")
        client_socket, port = self.server_socket.accept()
        self.client1 = ClientConnection(client_socket, port)
        print("Connection to Client1 established")
        client_socket, port = self.server_socket.accept()
        self.client2 = ClientConnection(client_socket, port)
        print("Connection to Client2 established")

    def handle_clients(self):
        self.client1_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(self.client1,))
        self.client2_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle_client, args=(self.client2,))
        self.client1_thread.start()
        self.client2_thread.start()

    def handle_client(self, client_connection):
        print("Started handling client")
        while True:
            msg = client_connection.socket.recv(1024)
            print("Client sent: " + msg.decode())
            client_connection.socket.send("Hello from server".encode())


class ClientConnection:
    def __init__(self, socket, port):
        self.socket = socket
        self.port = port



if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server()
    server.setup_server_and_bind()
    server.connect_to_clients()
    server.handle_clients()
    server.client1_thread.join()
    server.client2_thread.join()
```

Unity Client Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

public class SendSegments
{
    const int PORT = 123;
    const string IP = "123.123.123.1";
    #region private members     
    private TcpClient socketConnection;
    private Thread clientReceiveThread;
    #endregion

    public SendSegments()
    {
        ConnectToTcpServer();
    }

    /// <summary>   
    /// Setup socket connection.    
    /// </summary>  
    public void ConnectToTcpServer()
    {
        try
        {
            clientReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
            clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
            clientReceiveThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>   
    /// Runs in background clientReceiveThread; Listens for incoming data.  
    /// </summary>     
    private void ListenForData()
    {
        try
        {
            socketConnection = new TcpClient(IP, PORT);
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[10240];
            while (true)
            {
                // Get a stream object for reading              
                using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    // Read incoming stream into byte array.
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        var incomingData = new byte[length];
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incomingData, 0, length);
                        // Convert byte array to string message.                        
                        string serverMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incomingData);
                        Debug.Log("server message received as: " + serverMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>   
    /// Send message to server using socket connection.     
    /// </summary>  
    public void SendBytes(byte[] clientMessageAsByteArray)
    {
        if (socketConnection == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // Get a stream object for writing.             
            NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                stream.Write(clientMessageAsByteArray, 0, clientMessageAsByteArray.Length);
                Debug.Log("Client sent his message - should be received by server");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException socketException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
        }
    }
}
```

Python client Code:

```py
import socket
HOST = '123.123.123.1'
PORT = 123
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
except Exception as e:
    print("Cannot connect to the server:", e)
print("Connected")

sock.send("Client1".encode())
print(sock.recv(1024).decode())
sock.recv(1024)
```

Because the server waits for two connections, I run a unity client from phone/pc and a python demo client from pc. The unity client works on pc but not on phone.

Comment: Can be. But why are you not even showing how you try to connect?

Comment: and where exactly is the question?